# facebook share not adding image

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have facebook tabs app. and inside there I have share button

```
<p class="share-btn" id="button">share this</p>

<script>

    (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: 'app id',
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true,
            version: 'v2.8'
        });

        window.facebookShare = function (callback) {
            var id = @Model.Id;

            var options = ({
                method: 'share',
                href: 'https://www.facebook.com/my app url here&app_data=' + id
            }),
                status = '';

            FB.ui(options, function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                if (response && !response.error_code) {
                    status = 'success';
                    $.event.trigger('fb-share.success');

                } else {
                    status = 'error';
                    $.event.trigger('fb-share.error');
                }

                if (callback && typeof callback === "function") {
                    callback.call(this, status);
                } else {
                    return response;
                }
            });
        }

    };



    $('#button').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        facebookShare(function (response) {
            // simple function callback
            //console.log(response);
        });
    });

    // custom jQuery events
    $(document)
        .on('fb-share.success', function (e) {
            window.location.href = "/Quiz/Finished";
        })
        .on('fb-share.error', function (e) {
            //alert("fail");
        });
</script>
```

this shares link ok but it is not adding thumbnail. share looks this:

[image]

But in my layout I have these:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.your-domain.com/your-page.html" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Your Website Title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Your description" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/AspnetPaths/SelectImage.png" />
```

how can I do that? and is there any chance to pass image using options?

Comment: If you want the meta tags of _your_ URL to have any effect, than you have to share _your_ URL. Redirect human users from there to your page tab if you like.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this tool with your URL

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

it will tell you the exact error.

Greetings!

Comment: thanks but it says: `Warning
Facebook URLs cannot be crawled.`

Comment: Which url is the one you are trying?